# VBA count non empty elements of array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Noob question: I want to count the non empty elements of an array?

My attempt:

```
Dim Arr(1 To 15) As Double
'populating some of the elements of Arr
'...

Dim nonEmptyElements As Integer, i As Integer
nonEmptyElements = 0: i = 0
For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    If Not Arr(i) = "" Then
        nonEmptyElements = nonEmptyElements + 1
    End If
Next
```

With this program I get the error: Type mismatch on If statement.

If try to change the if condition to `If Not IsEmpty(Arr(i)) Then` and i get `nonEmptyElements = 15` as a result.

Any suggestions on how to complete the code?

Comment: You're defining Arr as Double so can't contain "empty" elements like it could if it was variant. They're always a number. So I think the program is working right, just not doing what you're looking for. Say more about what your goal is?

Comment: I see so 0 is the "empty element"

Comment: Can the array contain 0 as an element ? If not, write the if statement as below: If Arr(i) <> 0 Then

Comment: If you wanted to treat it that way. May depend on your application. may be ok for, say, lottery system, where lottery number is never zero. For accounting system where a budget amount could be zero you would need to use variant type to allow "true blanks".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Dim Arr(0 To 15) As Double
    Arr(6) = 1.2
    Arr(3) = 7
    Dim nonEmptyElements As Integer, i As Integer
    nonEmptyElements = 0 : i = 0
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        If Not Arr(i) = 0 Then
            nonEmptyElements = nonEmptyElements + 1
        End If
    Next
```

A double value by default is 0.0, so check if:

```
Arr(i) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.CountA(myarray)
```

CountA is a worksheet function for counting non-empty values.

Applies only to VBA6, does not work in VBA7.

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers you're right, but note that it worked in VBA6. CountA behavior is different in VBA6 and VBA7.